# Get memberof attribute of contact in Office365

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

Is there a way to get the distribution groups of a contact/user in Office365? I can't see memberof attribute.

```
Get-MailContact -Identity Username | Format-List
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it with `Get-ADObject`:

```
$Contact = Get-MailContact -Identity Username
(Get-ADObject -Identity $Contact.DistinguishedName -Properties 'MemberOf').MemberOf
```

Or (might take a bit more time) without AD-Module:

```
$Contact = Get-MailContact -Identity Username
Get-DistributionGroup | ? {Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_ | ? {$_.PrimarySmtpAddress -eq $Contact.PrimarySmtpAddress}}
```